# Range Behavior on Isolines

Tags: here-api

When retrieving reverse isolines based on time with a list of ranges does anyone know the behavior?

For example if range is 50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400 the polygon for 50 is much different then if range is 50,100,150.

Based on the two parameter sets below the range is extremely different for the 30 second revere isoline range. The two calls occurred at the same time.

For https://isoline.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?apiKey=xxxx&mode=balanced;car;traffic:default;motorway:-3&rangeType=time&destination=geo!43.805388,-79.525348&range=30,1800.

The polygon is:
"isoline": [{
"range": 30,
"component": [{
"id": 0,
"shape": ["43.8079834,-79.5238495",
"43.8066101,-79.5204163",
"43.8038635,-79.5204163",
"43.8024902,-79.5245361",
"43.8038635,-79.528656",
"43.8066101,-79.5293427",
"43.8079834,-79.5272827",
"43.8079834,-79.5238495"]
}]
}

For https://isoline.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?apiKey=xxxx&mode=balanced;car;traffic:default;motorway:-3&rangeType=time&destination=geo!43.805388,-79.525348&range=30.

The polygon is:
"isoline": [{
"range": 30,
"component": [{
"id": 0,
"shape": ["43.8059235,-79.5258236",
"43.8059235,-79.5245361",
"43.8057518,-79.5240211",
"43.8054085,-79.5240211",
"43.8050652,-79.5250511",
"43.8047218,-79.5253944",
"43.8047218,-79.5257378",
"43.8054085,-79.5264244",
"43.8057518,-79.5265102",
"43.8059235,-79.5262527",
"43.8059235,-79.5258236"]
}]
}]

Comment: Can you please provide further information about your use case or may be some example to help you in a better way.

Comment: Examples added.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is same as single range, just that multiple range allows calculation of many isolines with the same start or destination.

Check this link for your reference.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/isoline-routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/multi-range-isoline.html